# Get a number value from an object in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-native

I have a strange issue while working with data in state of a react-native component.

I first define the state:

```
    this.state = {
        bonesPosition: {
            black: [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 0}],
            white: [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 0}]
        }
    };
```

Then I update it:

```
const bonesPosition = {...this.state.bonesPosition};

bonesPosition.white[0].x = this.firstWhite.state.pan.x;

this.setState({bonesPosition})
```

But when I try to access the data,

```
const whiteX = this.state.bonesPosition.white[index].x;

console.log(whiteX)
console.log(typeof whiteX)
console.log(parseInt(whiteX))
console.log(Number(whiteX))
```

It shows me the value but I can calculate with it, because it is an object. But if I try to convert it to a number, it doesn't recongnize the number value anymore.

```
44.5
object
NaN
NaN
```

Any idea?

Comment: because it's already a number?

Comment: `whiteX` is an `object`, not a `number` or `string`. So, `parseInt` most probably will fail. `whiteX` may be an object with overridden `toString` or `valueOf` method(s). You need to deep dive into the implementation to find out the exact issue.

Comment: and why number or string is not an object?

Comment: What is `this.firstWhite.state.pan.x`?

Comment: can you set a debugger and check what is the prototype of `whiteX`?

Comment: `.toString()` gives me `[object Object]` and `valueOf()` returns `NaN`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could it be, that you have an Animated.Value instead of a simple number?

Deducing from the `pan` and bonesPosition this looks like code for a `panResponder`

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#tracking-gestures

You should inspect what kind of value/ object you are getting back and read through the Animations documentation.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, thank you!

I had to change `this.firstWhite.state.pan.x` to `this.firstWhite.state._value.x`